# Fortran 90: How to correctly read an integer among other real

Tags: input, format, fortran, fortran90

I have created a Fortran 90 code to filter and convert the text output of another program in a csv form. The file contains a table with columns of various types (character, real, integer). There is a column that generally contains decimal values (probability values). **BUΤ, in some rows, where the value should be decimal "1.000", the value is actually integer "1".**

I use "F5.3" specifier to read this column and I have the same format statement for every row of the table. So, when the code finds "1", it reads ".001", because it does not find a decimal point.

**What ways could I use to correctly (and generally) read integers among other decimals?**
Could I specify "unformatted" input only for a number of "spaces"?

Comment: There is rarely need to specify nonzero `d` in the `fw.d` descriptor.

Comment: This is the best answer! I didn't think the obvious...
Please post it also as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data edit descriptor `fw.d` for floating point format specification is  *for input* normally used with zero `d` (it cannot be ommited). Nonzero `d` is used in the rare case when the floating point data is stored as scaled integers, or you do some unit conversion from the integer values.

Comment: A potential danger here -- w must be larger than the total field width between commas. If you csv happens to have a stray field with extra white space or extra decimals you'll read multiple (garbage) values for that field.  (use f1000.0 I guess..)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using list-directed input: use a * instead of a format specifier.   This would be for the entire read, not selected items.   Or you could read the lines into a string test their contents to decide how to read them.   If the sub-string has a decimal point: `read (string(M:N), '(F5.3)') value`.   If it doesn't, use a different format, e.g., perhaps read as as `F5.0`.

P.S.  "unformatted" is reading binary data without conversion ... it is a direct copy of the data from the file to the data item.   "listed-directed" is the Fortran term for reading & converting data without using a format specification.

Comment: @MakisH  if you need help pulling out those substrings you should say so, its not clear from you question if you may already do that. .. and read(string(m:n),*)value should work just fine.

Comment: I thought this isn't such an "elegant" way. I also need the strings and values in other columns. Although, thank you very much for the answer! :-D

Answer (score 0):

well here's someting new to me: f90 allows a mix of comma and space delimiters for a simple list directed read:

```
read(unit,*)v1,v2,v3,v4
```

with input

```
1.222  2 , 3.14 , 4
```

yields

```
1.222000  2.000000 3.140000 4.000000
```